Connect DJI Ryze Tello drone to WSL through ROS
I am a beginner programmer in Python and I am currently carrying a project that involves connecting a Tello drone to WSL (Ubuntu 22.04), using ROS2 (Humble distro).
I am using the DJItelloPy library, and here is my test code.
import logging
from djitellopy import Tello
Tello.LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

tello = Tello()
tello.connect()
print(tello.get_battery())

I connected to the drone's wifi, no Windows firewall enabled, I ran the code in WSL, but I get an error:
File "/home/maeri_n/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djitellopy/tello.py", line 533, in connect
    raise Exception('Did not receive a state packet from the Tello')
Exception: Did not receive a state packet from the Tello

I even forwarded the required ports (8889, 8890, 11111) to WSL, but same error. I do not know if there could be some other problem blocking the connection.
Moreover, the drone perfectly connects to Windows, since this code to display the drone's video frames works perfectly in Windows (I use VSCode):
import logging
from djitellopy import tello, Tello
import cv2
Tello.LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def video_tello(drone):
    while True:
        frame = drone.get_frame_read().frame
        cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    drone.end()

def main():
    drone = tello.Tello()

    drone.connect()

    drone.streamon()

    video_tello(drone)

main()

I am eagerly waiting for feedbacks.

I had the exact problem with you, and I also tried forwarding ports with
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8890 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8890 connectaddress=<WSL_IP_Address>

But it seems to only forward tcp port. So I tried setting networkingMode=mirrored in .wslconfig and it worked!
Here is the  document
I think it sets the ip of wsl to be the same as windows in some way, so there is no more port forwarding issue.
